# rails api devise_token_auth How i can have multiple users for before actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api, devise-token-auth

I've a problem with **devise_token_auth** in rails api.
I need have **three different types of users**, and each user can see/edit different things.

But i don't know how i can to put before actions in controllers for each user. For example imagine that i have "service" controller with **CRUD** operations.

- I need that you are one of the three types of user to see index. If you aren't one of the types of users, you can't do anything.
- Admin can CRUD all.
- Other two users only can CR(create-read).

How do you do?

Comment: devise_token_auth is an authentication library.. I would suggest something to manage your roles like CanCanCan and rolify.